# website using default python interpreter instead of install virtualenv interpreter

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, centos, virtualenv

I have installed python 2.7 on centos.

I have created and activated a virtualenv associated with this interpreter.

My path looks like this:

```
/home/ec2-user/django-venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
```

When I hit my website i get the following error indicating that it is using the old version of python:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=19386): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/-django//wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/www/html/-django//wsgi.py", line 23, in <module>
   from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
   from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
   from django import http
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
   from django.http.request import (HttpRequest, QueryDict,
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 11, in <module>
   from django.conf import settings
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
   import importlib
 ImportError: No module named importlib
```

I created the the virtualenv like this:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 django-venv
```

I then activated it like this:

```
source django-venv/bin/activate
```

When i initiate "which python" I get the following output:

```
~/django-venv/bin/python
```

My apache httpd.conf entry looks like this:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/django/shared/static/

<Directory /var/www/html/django/shared/static/>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/django/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/django

<Directory /var/www/html/django>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

But I still get the error above that it is using the old python version of 2.6

How can I have my site use this virtualenv which points to the correct place?

Comment: What is the output of `which python` after you activated the virtual environment?

Comment: @mbatchkarov it outputs ~/django-venv/bin/python . I have updated this above as well

Comment: How are you activating it for the WSGI server?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added my wsgi info from httpd.conf above.  Does it need additional info to point to virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use the `wsgi.py` file generated by `manage.py startproject` and then put something like this in my httpd conf file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /full/path/to/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /full/path/to/django/project:/full/path/to/django-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

The official docs [cover this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

Answer (score 0):

If you just run it in the shell, that only affects that shell session, and doesn't even persist between logins, let alone affecting any system-wide services like Apache.

Normally you would put something in your wsgi.py:

```
activate_this = '/path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Comment: Is there a more standard way virtualenv works with django?  What does does activate_this.py contain?  Thanks for your help.